# I want to setup route in my project (react, typescript, react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I would like it to work in the form of the 3rd route. Previously, if it was used, Navigate would not be called to display the Navbar on the page of the component, but if Homepage or Product was called, the Navbar would initially be called. I tried creating it in the manner below by storing my Navbar and Components in an Array, but got a warning, so I tried to find new ways.

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

//pages
import ErrorPage from "@/pages/ErrorPage";
import LoginPage from "@/pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "@/pages/RegisterPage";

import Navigate from "@/components/Navigate";
import HomePage from "@/pages/HomePage";
import Products from "@/pages/Products";


const element = createRoutesFromElements(
  <>
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />

> I want to run the Navigate Component at once to be able to use it in the Homepage and Product Component.

    <Route path="/homepage" element={[<Navigate />, <HomePage />]} />
    <Route path="/products" element={[<Navigate />, <Products />]} />
  </>
);

export const router = createBrowserRouter(element);
```

Comment: "I want to run the Navigate Component at once to be able to use it in the Homepage and Product Component." - What is `Navigate`? Why do you want to unconditionally navigate when accessing routes? Where is the code navigating to?

Answer (score 1):

> You have to use `Outlet` component

An `<Outlet/>` should be used in parent route elements to render their child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child routes are rendered.

First thing you have to create an parent component, I am  calling it  `Layout` and wrap the common components like nav bar, footer.

`Layout.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigate from "@/components/Navigate";

export default function Layout(props){
  
    return (
        <div>
            <Navigate/>
            <Outlet/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then you have to create a route as normally and apply `index` prop to render default child route.

In `router`

```
import {
    createBrowserRouter,
    createRoutesFromElements,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

//pages
import ErrorPage from "@/pages/ErrorPage";
import LoginPage from "@/pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "@/pages/RegisterPage";

import Navigate from "@/components/Navigate";
import HomePage from "@/pages/HomePage";
import Products from "@/pages/Products";

import Layout from "@/pages/Layout";

const element = createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path="/homepage" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        </Route>
    </>
);

export const router = createBrowserRouter(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

My new code version 
router.tsx

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

//pages
import ErrorPage from "@/pages/ErrorPage";
import LoginPage from "@/pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "@/pages/RegisterPage";

// import Navigate from "@/components/Navigate";
import HomePage from "@/pages/HomePage";
import Products from "@/pages/Products";
import { Product } from "@/pages/Product";

import Layout from "@/pages/layout";

const element = createRoutesFromElements(
  <>
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index path="/homepage" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
      <Route path="products/:id" element={<Product />} />
    </Route>
  </>
);

export const router = createBrowserRouter(element);
```

layout.tsx

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigate from "@/components/Navigate";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigate />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navigation.tsx

```
import { Container, Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navigate() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="bg-body-tertiary">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand key={0} href="/homepage">
          @Shoes Store
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav" className="">
          <Nav className="w-100 justify-content-end">
            <NavLink
              key={1}
              className={({ isActive, isPending }) =>
                isPending
                  ? "pending"
                  : isActive
                  ? "nav-link active"
                  : "nav-link"
              }
              to="/homepage"
            >
              Homepage
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink
              key={2}
              className={({ isActive, isPending }) =>
                isPending
                  ? "pending"
                  : isActive
                  ? "nav-link active"
                  : "nav-link"
              }
              to="/products"
            >
              Products
            </NavLink>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).